# JavaScript: change href value when box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that links to a product page, like so...

```
<a href="/product.html" id="link"><button>Buy This</button></a>
```

And I need to change the value of href when a box is checked. This is what I have so far

```
document.getElementById(#option1).checked = true;
document.getElementById(#link).value = '/product/option1.html';
```

But it's not working.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You tagged this question with jQuery, why don't you use the jquery shortcut for document.getElementById?

Answer (score 7):

Of course it's not working...

1. `getElementById`, not `GetElementById` - case matters!
2. `'option1'`, not `#option1` - I don't know where you got the idea that `#option1` was right.
3. You are *setting* the `checked` property to `true`, meaning the checkbox will be set to checked.
4. You have no event handler at all, so this code will only run once, when the page loads, and won't update when the user toggles the box.
5. A link's href is in its `.href` property, not its `.value` (it doesn't actually have a `.value`)
6. You have a `<button>` inside an `<a>` tag. Not technically valid, although most browsers will work the way you'd expect. This isn't a guarantee though, and you should either use a link, or a JS event handler on the button.

With all that in mind, I present to you...

```
<button id="link">Buy this</button>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="option1" /> Option text</label>
```

```js
document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() {
    if( document.getElementById('option1').checked) {
        location.href = '/product/option1.html';
    }
    else {
        location.href = '/product.html';
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure why the hostile tone in some parts, but solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

You added `jquery` as a tag, if you're using it, try this:

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on("change", "#option1", function(){
    $("#link").attr("href", "https://www.google.com");
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice demo I made in JSFiddle...

[www.jsfiddle.net/Lvu5818f](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Lvu5818f)

```
document.getElementById("link").onclick = function() {
   var link = document.getElementById("link");
   var checkbox = document.getElementById("button");
   if(checkbox.checked){
      link.setAttribute("href", "#test2");
   }
   return true;
}

<a href="#test1"id="link"><button>Buy This</button></a>
    <br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="true" id="button">Add an extra T-Shirt</label>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="test1">This is some text a long way away...</div>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div id="test2">This is some text even farther away...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.GetElementById('#link').href= '/product/option1.html';
```